# Alt button not detected on some keymap shortcut IntelliJ (elementaryOS 5.1.7

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, elementary-os, azerty-keyboard

### Settings

- IntelliJ 2019.2 (same issue in 2020.2)
- elementary OS 5.1.7.
- AZERTY bluetooth Keyboard (Logitech K260)
- French Keyboard Layout
- French Input method
- No custom configuration made either in IntelliJ or in the OS

### Problem

The "Move Line Up/Down" shortcut I was using on Windows (Shift + Alt + Up/Down) is not working.

### Description

On intelliJ, I opened Settings/Keymap window to check the shortcut was correctly set.
When trying to redefine this shortcut, the "Alt" button was not detected when pressed.

However, I can use it on elementaryOS (e.g. Alt+Tab is working).

On intellij, I can use some other shortcuts like "Alt + Up".

My OS were recently installed.

I already tried to put UK layout/input method with no success.

### Two ideas:

- system settings : something i missed in keyboard settings ? Don't know much about linux configurations.
- IntelliJ option i'm missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue.

On elementaryOS,

- Go to your Keyboard settings, select "Layout" tab.
- On "Switch layout" options, change the default shortcut "Alt + Shift".

Then I am able to reuse this specific shortcut in IntelliJ.

See the screenshot below to get more information:
[Keyboard/Layout/Switch layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8HCH.png)